# Differentiability of norm

Tags: analysis

How to show if a norm in $X$ is differentiable at  $x_0 $, then $x_0  \neq 0$, $ A x_0 = \| x_0 \|$ and $\| A \|=1$

$$\frac{ \| x_0 +h \| - \| x_0 \|- A h}{ \| h \|} \le \frac{ \| x_0\| + \| h \| - \| x_0 \|- \| h \|  }{ \| h \|} = \frac{ 0 }{ \| h \|}=0$$ hat with case $x_0 = 0 $ and $x_0 \neq 0$
 $\| \cdot \|'(x_0)$:
Since $x_0 \neq 0$, then for $\frac{x_0}{ \| x_0 \|}$ we have
$\| \| \cdot \|'(x_0) \frac{x_0}{\| x_0 \|} \|= \|  \frac{x_0}{ \| x_0 \|} \| = 1$

Is it correct?

Comment: Sorry. I have misunderstood your question first. Concerning your proof. Why should the directional derivative in $h$ be $\|h\|$? That is only valid for particular $h$'s. Which is exactly what you have to prove. Hint: use $\|x_0\| - \|h\| \le \| x_0 + h\| \le \|x_0\| + \|h|$ and select $h$ accordingly.

Comment: This is Fréchet derivative:
$\lim_{h \to 0} \frac{\|x_0+h \|-\|h \| - A(h)}{\|h \|}=0$

Comment: $\| \cdot \|'(x_0)h$ is the directional derivative if the norm is differentiable at $x_0$. I was just too lazy to type out the formula on my phone.

Comment: I'm sorry, this is the Fréchet derivative and i have to prove it by this definition.

Comment: I don't see, how that makes your proof correct nor my hint useless. $Ah = \|h\|$ is only valid for particular choice of $h$!

Comment: Take the Euclidean norm, $x_0 = e_1$ and $h=e_2$. Then, the left hand side of your inequality is positive, not non-positive as you claimed.

Answer (score 1):

Assume $X\ne \{0\}$. Otherwise it would be unnecessarily pathological.

Remember that
$$ \lim_{h\to 0, h\ne 0} \frac{ \|x_0 + h\| - \|x_0\| - Ah }{\| h \|} = 0$$
implies 
$$ \lim_{t\to 0, t > 0} \frac{ \|x_0 + t h_0\| - \|x_0\|}{t} = A h_0 $$
for any fixed $h_0\ne 0$, by setting $h = t h_0$.

**Hints:**

1. "$x_0 \ne 0$": Let $h_0 \ne 0$. Show that 
   $$\lim_{t\to 0, t > 0} \frac{ \|x_0 + t h_0\| - \|x_0\|}{t} \ne -\left(\lim_{t\to 0, t > 0} \frac{ \|x_0 - t h_0\| - \|x_0\|}{t}\right). $$
2. "$Ax_0 = \|x_0\|$": $\|x_0 + tx_0\| = (1+t)\|x_0\|$ for $t > 0$.
3. "$\|A\|$ = 1": Triangular inequality implies 
   $$ \frac{|\|x_0 + t h_0\| - \| x_0 \||}{t} \le \|h_0\|, $$
   which gives you $\|A\| \le 1$. For $\| A \| = 1$ use 2.

Answer (score 1):

In general, if a differentiable function is Lipschitz of rank $L$, then we have
$\|Df(x)\| \le L$.

Since any norm satisfies $| \|x\| - \|y\| | \le \|x-y\|$ (using the triangle inequality), we see that $\|A\| \le 1$.

We also have that the directional derivative satisfies $df(x,h) = \lim_{t\to 0} {f(x+th)-f(x) \over t} = Df(x) h$.

Letting $n(x) = \|x\|$, we see that $n(x_0+t x_0) = (1+t) n(x_0)$ for $t \ge -1$, from which we get $dn(x_0, x_0) = n(x_0) = \|x_0\| = Dn(x_0) x_0$.

The latter also shows that $\|Dn(x_0)\| \ge 1$, combining this with the fact that the norm is Lipschitz with rank 1 gives the desired result.