# Norm in complex space

Tags: analysis

How to show that a norm in complex space $X$ isn't differentiable (Frechet) at every point $x \in X$. I don't know how to prove to it.

By definition, we know that if a function is differentiable at $x$, then
$$\lim\limits_{a \to 0} \frac{\|f(x+a)-f(x)-A(x)(a)\|}{\|a\|} = 0.$$

Comment: [Very, very similar question from a few hours ago](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/1465424)

Answer (score 2):

Pick $x$ with $\|x\|=1$ and let $\phi(t) = \|tx\| = |t|$. Since $\phi$ is
not differentiable at zero, $x \mapsto \|x\|$ cannot be either.